How to efficiently make a large matrix of 1s and 0s
I have two numpy arrays x and y of same length, and I am trying to make a square matrix A such that the (i,j) entry of the matrix will contain a 1 if a certain relationship holds between x[i], x[j], y[i] and y[j], and a 0 otherwise.
The current method I have for this is starting with A as a zero matrix (of dimensions len(x) by len(x)) and then using a double for loop to range over all i, and all j>i (this matrix is symmetric in the diagonal). However this takes a really really long time to run - the length of x is around 15,000. The vast majority of entries in A will be 0, so this seems to be quite an inefficient way of doing this. I thought that potentially masked arrays could be used but I haven’t figured out how to use them in this situation. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Here is the code I currently have: df is a data frame in which one column contains surnames and another a date.
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['Smith', '2024-12-16 12:00:00'], ['Smith', '2024-12-16 13:00:00'], ['Doe', '2024-12-16 12:01:00'], ['Doe', '2024-12-16 12:04:00']])# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
df1.columns = ['Surname', 'Date']
df1['Date'] = df1.apply(lambda r : datetime.strptime(r['Date'], date_format),1)

x1 = df1['Surname'].to_numpy()
y1 = df1['Date'].to_numpy()

A1 = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix((len(df1.index), len(df1.index))).todense()
for i in range(len(x1)):
    for j in range(i, len(x1)):
        A1[i,j] = int((x1[i] == x1[j]) & (abs(np.timedelta64(y1[i]-y1[j], 'm')) < np.timedelta64(5, 'm')))


Please provide a [mre]

It will be easier to understand if you give an example instead of a description.

Also you say x and y are numpy arrays but then tag the question with sparse-matrix. Which one is it? numpy.array or scipy sparse matrix?

@Homer512 x and y are numpy arrays but I have been using A as a scipy sparse matrix

The code you posted is not a [mre]. An MRE is a snippet of code that I can copy-and-paste into my own interpreter and it will run. I don't have your dataframe df. It's also supposed to be minimal. Your dataframe has no meaning for the question and just complicates the picture. Please read the help section on how to ask a good question before asking.

« if a certain relationship holds » : what relationship? You can't have a generic answer. The nature of this relationship changes everything. Is it the one of your code (which is a bit strange. What are the types of y? datetimes? Then why the conversion of a difference into a timedelta that it is already? Or numbers? Then why timedeltas?).

Note: "efficiently" depends on the use. Just for storage it is just a string of n*n bits (so few modulo operations you get the position). But if we use "matrix" usually we want to make more, and so it depends: which operation should be done efficiently?

Besides, you create an empty sparse matrix, but just to convert it into a dense matrix (which is not a view. It is a copy). You would be better off just using numpy.zeros if that was the goal. I feel that you think that A is still stored in memory in "sparse" way, and that it is a dense view on a sparse matrix. It is not. It is a numpy array (or almost so).

@GiacomoCatenazzi apologies when I say efficiently I just want the code to run as fast as possible, I don't care about how big the matrix is for storage purposes

@chrslg I'm new to most of python and so I'm sure I am not doing things in the most efficient way. The y are datetimes.

One solution is to convert one of the comparison arrays to a 2d array (transposed), through x1[:, np.newaxis] (which is equivalent to x1[:, None], see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis):
(
    # comparison 1
    (x1[:, np.newaxis] == x1) &
    # comparison 2
    (
        abs(
            (y1[:, np.newaxis] - y1)
            .astype('timedelta64[m]')
        )
        < np.timedelta64(5, 'm')
    )
# convert to 2d Boolean array to integer
).astype(int)

